# What do I do if it looks like I have a Stack Overflow user that is messing with me?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation, users

I have some strange multiple undownvotes, downvotes, and reputation movement on my Stack Overflow account over the last 2 days:

6 - yesterday

- +2    03:00  undownvote  defining date in json file
- +2    03:00  undownvote  How to locate places nearby to my custom markers
- +2    03:00  undownvote  How to prevent map marker from snapping to road

-10 - 2 days ago

- -2    16:19  downvote    Google Places API - find an address using the city
- -2    15:47  downvote    How to locate places nearby to my custom markers
- -2    15:47  downvote    How to prevent map marker from snapping to road
- -2    15:47  downvote    defining date in json file
- -2    15:46  downvote    drawing polygon with addition/moving/deletion of points

And I'm pretty sure I have a user that is messing with me. How do I handle this situation? And are there steps I should take if I have a suspicion which user is the culprit?

Comment: Seems like somebody with a grudge who's not willing to lose a lot of reputation :)

Comment: Someone thought you needed to be punished for daring to try and help them. They've been warned, and the votes invalidated.

Comment: I'm not touching you I'm not touching you!

Comment: see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129054/173001) question, its reverse case from yours, but answer would same in that case :)

Comment: Is this related? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127637/why-are-these-reversed-downvotes-recorded-as-undownvotes

Comment: @Bolt: yes. (Both were invalidated revenge votes).

Comment: @Shog9, someone is also downvoting on my question on SO, but step by step

Comment: Hmm? @Lucifer I see no sign of this... http://stackoverflow.com/users/996493/lucifer?tab=reputation

Comment: @Shog9, i was talking about my meta [reputation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/173001/lucifer?tab=reputation), have a look at it. i flagged for it,which result in **helpful**

Comment: Oh, ok @Lucifer. I did a quick check on your meta account, and it doesn't appear that anyone has been specifically targeting you (one user gave you two consecutive down-votes, but that doesn't really mean much by itself). I would assume the moderator who handled that flag did the same and marked it "helpful" because, while your rep history does look suspicious, there's nothing incriminating behind it. Keep in mind: some folks tend to down-vote a *lot* more on MSO than on other sites.

Comment: @Shog9, ok, thanks for reviewing :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I saw your reputation tab, it was a serial downvote. There is a script running on the Stack Overflow, which takes care of **Serial Upvotes** and **Serial Downvotes**. The action gets revert back by this script.

However still you can flag any of your question/answer mentioning a sentence **This could be a false downvoting, kindly look into it** to the moderator for more confirmation. If it is really done be a single user or multiple user just for fun or tease you, then it will surely revert back.

As you can see in yesterday's action, three of your downvotes get revert back by the system itself, so you dont need to worry much.

Comment: the system did not revert those...

Comment: how do you know that @yoda ?

Comment: Hmmm. They all do have the same timestamps...

Comment: wow... now there is serial downvoting on my reputation tab :P

Comment: Ignore my earlier comment - this was the script; it did look odd though.

Comment: okey  status-ignored :)